# How do I click on 2nd html element which is a duplicate of first element using selenium and python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to click on an element that is copied throughout the website (it is a button), but how do I click on lets say the second button, not the first. 
Here is the code of the button I want to click:

```
<a href="/us/en/outletus/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-x-series/ThinkPad-X280/p/20KFCTO1WW-PC0YQ4GF" class="button-called-out button-full facetedResults-cta">SHOP NOW</a>
```

However, the issue is that sometimes it may greyed out if the item is not in stock so I don't want to click it
As a result, here is all of my code:

```
def mainclick(website):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        price_saved = [i.text.replace('$', "").replace(',', '') for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[itemprop=youSave]')]
        print(price_saved)
        for g in range(len(price_saved)):
            a = g + 1
            if float(price_saved[g]) > 200:
                try:
                    driver.find_element_by_link_text("SHOP NOW")[a].click()
                    time.sleep(3)
                    try:
                        driver.find_element_by_id("addToCartButtonTop").click()
                        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
                    except:
                        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
                except:
                    print("couldn't click")
                    pass
            print(a)
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next Page").click()
    print("all pages done")
# starts time
start_time = time.time()
mainweb = "https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/outletus/laptops/c/LAPTOPS?q=%3Aprice-asc%3AfacetSys-Memory%3A16+GB%3AfacetSys-Processor%3AIntel%C2%AE+Core%E2%84%A2+i7%3AfacetSys-Processor%3AIntel%C2%AE+Core%E2%84%A2+i5%3AfacetSys-Memory%3A8+GB&uq=&text=#"
driver.get(mainweb)
mainclick(mainweb)
```

I tried using [a] to click on a certain one but it doesn't seem to work. Also, the href might change of the shop now button based on the product.

Comment: What is purpose of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath with an index a:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[.='SHOP NOW'])[{}]".format(a))
```

Note that the first element has index 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the elements using `.find_elements*`.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('insert_value_here')
elements[0].click()
```

The above example to click first elements.

This index `[0]`, replace with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that everytime you want to click on 2nd button
try using below xpath,

```
(//*[@class='button-called-out button-full facetedResults-cta'])[2]
```

If, count of buttons is not same ( may be greyed out) 
try using findelements

```
List button=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='button-called-out button-full facetedResults-cta']"));

button.size();
```

Append the button.size() to the xpath in the place of '2' dynamically, you can click on the second/first not greyed button